# Is it damaging or detrimental to share an OS with 2 different machines, laptop and desktop?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems

I have 2 computers:

1. i5-8400 Desktop,  Windows 10, 64 bit
2. i3-7100u Laptop,  Windows 10, 64 bit

I shuttle the OS on SSD between both machines, been doing this for years with no issues, the SSD has an adapter so I don't damage the ports by moving the SSD in and out depending if I work at home on desktop or go out with laptop.

Now this works flawlessly, when switching, it goes into "getting devices ready" and then boots up no problem on either machine.

I've heard this is not a good idea, can a pro elaborate on why ? Or is this totally ok?

Would I benefit with an independent OS per machines and shared data disk?

Comment: I think that you answer your own question when you say "`been doing this for years with no issues`"

Comment: Yes, but I was advised on a hardware forum that it's not a good idea, so wanted to double check

Comment: All that I can think of is that you might end up with extra drivers and registry entries for programs installed on one PC but not on the other. Mabe also a few "wrong" defaults half the time.  Also, if your swap file is on the same drive, it might become confusing.  I don't see how it could cause damage though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux this is not damaging, and at worst there may be some confusion on device enumeration which can possibly be overcome by playing with udev. This is largely because Linux packs most common drivers alongside the kernel.

The situation for Windows is somewhat murkier. Windows generally has fewer drivers packaged so swapping devices can be trickier. If you have similar (chipset) systems this may workand and the constant "setting up devices" is likely modifying some drivers each time you swap. Where you will likely run into trouble is with licensing - it is probably that Windows will see itself sharing 1 license between more then 1 device and may not like it. From a hardware POV this should not cause damage though.

Having 2OS's and a separate/shared data drive is probably a better seup in terms of data vs OS separation and flexibility, but YMMV.